# Variable 'result' might not have been initialized

Tags: java

```js
public class MonthName {
  public static String month_name(int month) {
    String result;

    if (month == 1) {
      result = "January";
    } else if (month == 2) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 3) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 4) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 5) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 6) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 7) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 8) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 9) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 10) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 11) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 12) {
      result = "February";
    }

    return result;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Month 1: " + month_name(1));
    System.out.println("Month 2: " + month_name(2));
    System.out.println("Month 3: " + month_name(3));
    System.out.println("Month 4: " + month_name(4));
    System.out.println("Month 5: " + month_name(5));
    System.out.println("Month 6: " + month_name(6));
    System.out.println("Month 7: " + month_name(7));
    System.out.println("Month 8: " + month_name(8));
    System.out.println("Month 9: " + month_name(9));
    System.out.println("Month 10: " + month_name(10));
    System.out.println("Month 11: " + month_name(11));
    System.out.println("Month 12: " + month_name(12));
    System.out.println("Month 43: " + month_name(43));
  }
}
```

So I have declared the relevant string's value into the result but it still says my variable 'result' might not have been initialized.

I'm trying to achieve the output similar to [this](http://programmingbydoing.com/a/month-name.html).
Any one could help me on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this can occur if your variable month may be empty or something <1 or >12. You can probably solve this in simply removing the last if in your `if-else` tree for example like this:

```js
public class MonthName {
  public static String month_name(int month) {
    String result = "";

    if (month == 1) {
      result = "January";
    } else if (month == 2) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 3) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 4) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 5) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 6) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 7) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 8) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 9) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 10) {
      result = "February";
    } else if (month == 11) {
      result = "February";
    } else {
      result = "February";
    }

    return result;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Month 1: " + month_name(1));
    System.out.println("Month 2: " + month_name(2));
    System.out.println("Month 3: " + month_name(3));
    System.out.println("Month 4: " + month_name(4));
    System.out.println("Month 5: " + month_name(5));
    System.out.println("Month 6: " + month_name(6));
    System.out.println("Month 7: " + month_name(7));
    System.out.println("Month 8: " + month_name(8));
    System.out.println("Month 9: " + month_name(9));
    System.out.println("Month 10: " + month_name(10));
    System.out.println("Month 11: " + month_name(11));
    System.out.println("Month 12: " + month_name(12));
    System.out.println("Month 43: " + month_name(43));
  }
}
```

This says means your variable have to be something between 1 and 12 and otherwise you should throw an exception. But anyway, I won't use those if-else tree all the way down. Too much redundancy anyway.

This this instead:

```
switch (month) {
case 1:  result = "January";
         break;
case 2:  result = "February";
         break;
case 3:  result = "March";
         break;
case 4:  result = "April";
         break;
case 5:  result = "May";
         break;
case 6:  result = "June";
         break;
case 7:  result = "July";
         break;
case 8:  result = "August";
         break;
case 9:  result = "September";
         break;
case 10: result = "October";
         break;
case 11: result = "November";
         break;
case 12: result = "December";
         break;
default: result = "Invalid month";
         break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

local variables should be initialized before use .they don't have default values

initialize it

```
String result="";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `month` is just an `int` it can take on values other than `1`-`12` (what your `if`/`else/if` structure handles).

To get rid of the error, you could just initialize it to the empty `String`, however, you may want to consider error cases.

For example what should the method do, if passed something not in the `1`-`12` range?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `result` has not been initialized. The `result` will only contain a value when the input is between 1 and 12.

You can try this while declaring the variable

```
String result = "";
```

or this so that you don't need to add another line for setting result to error.

```
String result = "error";
```